# Enviar Json vía Serial de Arduino Uno a ESP8266

Tags: c++, arduino

Trabajó en un proyecto en el cual necesito pasar un json con datos procesados por varios sensores a la placa Esp8266 vía Serial o alguna otra cosa ya que esos datos deben poder visualizarse desde la url que generó con el microserver para poder visualizarlos en el navegador. La idea es que por medio de un sitio web pueda hacer una petición vía GET a la IP del arduino y poder obtener los datos desde allí.
Ya he intentado codificar el json y mandarlo por el Serial pero al tratar de obtenerlo desde arduino o no llega entero o de plano no llega. ¿Alguien ha logrado hacer algo parecido? Saludos!

**Edit**

Esto es lo que he intentado:

**Arduino Uno**

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define ESP_SERIAL_RX 2
#define ESP_SERIAL_TX 3

String dataJSON;
int height = 0;
float weight = 0;

SoftwareSerial ESPserial(ESP_SERIAL_RX, ESP_SERIAL_TX);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  ESPserial.begin(57600);
}

void loop() {
  delay(50);
  // logica para establecer height y weight 

  createJSON();
  sendLineToESP(dataJSON);
}

void createJSON() {
  String j1 = "{\"version\":\"1.0\",\"height\":";
  String j2 = ", \"weight\":";
  String j3 = "}";
  dataJSON = j1 + height + j2 + weight + j3;
}

void sendLineToESP(String line) {
  if (ESPserial.available()){
    ESPserial.print(line);
  } else {
    Serial.println("ESP no disponible.");
  }
}
```

**ESP8266**

```
String dataJson = "{\"version\":\"1.0\",\"height\":0, \"weight\":0}";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(57600);
  // logica adicional...
}

void loop() {
  getDataFromSerial();
  // ...
}

void getDataFromSerial() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    Serial.println(dataJSON);
    dataJson = Serial.readString();
  }
}
```

Comment: https://arduinojson.org/

Comment: Aporta alguna de las pruebas que hayas hecho, seguro que hay alguien que te echa una mano si se lo pones fácil :) https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Ya he agregado el código que tengo, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

**La función `available`**

Estas usando mal la función `available()`. Esta función te dice **cuantos** caracteres hay disponibles para lectura en el buffer de entrada, no si es posible escribir algo de salida (esa sería la función `Serial.availableForWrite()`, que aquí no se necesita).

Por tanto, toda esta función puede ser reemplazada con una simple instrucción

```
void sendLineToESP(String line) {
  if (ESPserial.available()){
    ESPserial.print(line);
  } else {
    Serial.println("ESP no disponible.");
  }
}
```

reemplazar con

```
ESPserial.print(line);
```

No necesitas preguntar si hay espacio disponible antes de hacer `print`. Arduino se encarga de ese problema.

**Lectura serial**

En Arduino, todas las lecturas del puerto serial son potencialmente incompletas, por lo que tienes que entrar en un bucle hasta tener todos los caracteres del mensaje.

La función `Serial.readString()` puede terminar por timeout y retornar sin leer el mensaje completo.

La solución es usar `Serial.readStringUntil('\n')`, que va a leer desde la puerta serial hasta encontrar un '\n' (o cualquier otro caracter que quieras usar como delimitador).